# c# Thread Ожидать завершение работы потока

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть код

```
          for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        {
             
            if (SerwiseList["One"] == true)
            {
                log.Report("Старт");
                Thread thread1 = new Thread(Start); // Создаём поток 1
                thread1.Start(); // Запуск потока 1
                 
                thread1.Join();
                thread1.Abort();
            }
                         
         }
```

Мне нужно выполнить метод Start() 5 раз, при этом нужно запустить поток, дождаться пока он завершит работу, затем выполнить его повторно.

> Метод **Join** блокирует выполнение вызвавшего его потока до тех пор, пока не завершится поток, для которого был вызван данный метод

У меня он не работает, цикл выполняеться сразу 5 раз подряд

Как можно приостановить основной поток пока поток thread1 не завершит работу?

UPD

Метод Start

```
   async  public void Start()
    {
            for (int j = 0; j < CountUpdates; j++)
            {
                log.Report(await httpClient.Check(link);

            }
       
    }
```

Start() обращаеться к методу  httpClient.Check(link)

```
  public async Task<string> Check(string url)
    {

        try
        {
             
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("url", url),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("app", "site"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("version", "0.1"),
        });
                var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
                string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();



                return resultContent;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

UPD2
Ответ @aepot помог, но появилась навая проблема

```
  for (int i = 0; i < linkList.Length; i++)
        {
            if (SerwiseList["One"])
            {
                log.Report("Старт 1");
                await Start();
            }
            if (SerwiseList["Two"])
            {
                log.Report("Старт 2");
                await Start2();
            }
            if (SerwiseList["Three"])
            {
                log.Report("Старт 3");
                await Start3();
            }
        }
```

Метод Start2() начинает работу только после того как закончит выполняться Start(), Start3() работает только после того как завершит работу Start2()

При испольовании Thread  Start(), Start2() и Start3() работали паралельно

```
          if (SerwiseList["One"] == true)
            {
                log.Report("Старт");
                Thread thread1 = new Thread(Start); // Создаём поток 1
                thread1.Start(); // Запуск потока 1
            }
           if (SerwiseList["Two"])
            {
                log.Report("Старт 2");
                Thread thread1 = new Thread(Start2); // Создаём поток 1
                thread1.Start(); // Запуск потока 1
            }
            if (SerwiseList["Three"])
            {
                log.Report("Старт 3");
                Thread thread1 = new Thread(Start3); // Создаём поток 1
                thread1.Start(); // Запуск потока 1
            }
```

Comment: Уберите `Abort`, его нельзя использовать, никогда и нигде - долгая история, не буду сейчас ее рассказывать. Только я не вижу смысла в потоках, если вы все равно выполняете их последовательно. Расскажите, что с вашим кодом сейчас не так. Он не работает? Как вы это поняли? Покажите вызываемый метод.

Comment: пролейте свет на задачу, это прольёт свет на решение

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1584062/4269118

Comment: Покажите код метода `Start`, тут всё кроме лишнего `Abort` выглядит нормально.

Comment: aepot,  код работает, мне нужно дождаться пока поток thread1  завершит работу, затем завершить его и запустить его заново. То есть, мне нужно выполнить метод Start(), дождаться пока он завершит работу, затем выпонить его заново.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну вот теперь все понятно, `async void`.

При этом вы пытаетесь в потоке запустить и без того асинхронный метод. Представьте что вы пнули мячик и отвернулись не дожидаясь как он долетит, вот это `async void`. А `Thread` разница в том, что вы просите пнуть этот мячик соседа, он так же ничего не будет дожидаться.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
    if (SerwiseList["One"])
    {
        log.Report("Старт");
        await Start();
    }                         
}
```

```
public async Task Start()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < CountUpdates; j++)
    {
        log.Report(await httpClient.Check(link));
    }
}
```

**UPD**

Давайте по одной проблеме на вопрос. Если после полученного ответа у вас появляется новый вопрос, отметьте ответ принятым, и задайте новый вопрос отдельно.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < linkList.Length; i++)
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>()
    if (SerwiseList["One"])
    {
        log.Report("Старт 1");
        tasks.Add(Start());
    }
    if (SerwiseList["Two"])
    {
        log.Report("Старт 2");
        tasks.Add(Start2());
    }
    if (SerwiseList["Three"])
    {
        log.Report("Старт 3");
        tasks.Add(Start3());
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: Да уж, мало того, что `Thread` и `Task` в одну кучу, так ещё и `async void`, прям все ошибки сразу товарищ собрал )

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, но появилась новая проблема.. Добавил в первое сообщение код

Comment: @WyWyWy обновил ответ. Почитайте [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async), я использую самые примитивные асинхронные шаблоны, которые вам надо бы поизучать. Как ожидать таски, как ожидать несколько тасков сразу, как запустить 100500 тасок, но при этом чтобы работало только 10 одновременно, и так далее. Это все типовые задачи. И если вы добрались до тасок и асинхронности, забудьте уже про `Thread`.